# Need help getting past a user verification failed message setting up ASP.Net MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to set up an ASP.Net MVC project that will use Azure Active Directory. I keep getting an error informing me that my user verification failed.

Here are the steps leading to the error message:

1. In VS 2013 Web Express, select New ASP.Net Web Application
2. Select MVC Template
3. Click change authentication button
4. Select Organizational Accounts option
5. Fill out form and click
6. A window pops up asking to verify password of my MS account

At this point I get an error message telling me that my user verification failed.

I do have an Azure Account. I do have directory set up in AAD.

Anyone have some guidance on setting up this project?

Comment: Sounds like the account you are using for Azure AD is not correct. I do not have any exp in this area but I found this article that may help you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn151790.aspx good luck.

Comment: @Tony, your link leads me to think I need to associate the directory with an app first. I thought more recent updates to AAD and VS allowed me to create the app in AAD while creating the project. At leaset that's what I thought after watching a demo from the recent BUILD conference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a page on the ASP.Net site. [Organizational account authentication options](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#orgauthoptions)

> Don’t enter credentials for a Microsoft account (for example, contoso@hotmail.com) in the sign-in dialog box.

The sticking point was I did what the above quote says I should not do.

Comment: How did you get passed the sign-on dialog?

Comment: I originally used my MS account, and that was not working. I created a new user in Azure Active Directory and used that account when creating the project. I was then able to complete creating the project, build, and view in IIS Express. Note the "Organizational account authentication options" section in the link above.